# mySQL sorting by parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Have a sql request:

```
SELECT
`e` .*,
`cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`,
`price_index`.`price`,
`price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
`price_index`.`final_price`,
IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL,
LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price),
price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`,
`price_index`.`min_price`,
`price_index`.`max_price`,
`price_index`.`tier_price`
FROM
`catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store2` AS `cat_index` ON
cat_index.product_id = e.entity_id
AND cat_index.store_id = '2'
AND cat_index.visibility IN(2,4)
AND cat_index.category_id = '153'
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON
price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id
AND price_index.website_id = '3'
AND price_index.customer_group_id = '1'
WHERE
((`e`.`sku` IN('96005', '5806', '96004','PROD91','PROD187')))
    AND (e.created_in <= '1548056609')
    AND (e.updated_in > '1548056609')
```

And I get this result:

[image]

But I need to get it in order like inside IN:
96005','5806','96004', 'PROD91','PROD187'

Comment: Add line breaks, please.

Comment: What is the logic behind the target odering?

Comment: I need the same order as inside IN expression

Comment: Just add `ORDER BY FIELD(e.sku, '96005', '5806', '96004','PROD91','PROD187')`

Answer (score 0):

use "case" statement
ex:

```
SELECT * FROM 
...
ORDER BY case when <your_value> = '96005' then 1
          when <your_value> = '5806' then 2
          when <your_value> = '96004' then 3
          when <your_value> = 'PROD91' then 4
          when <your_value> = 'PROD187' then 5
```